# Complex preprocessor macro

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm creating a category of `UIColor` where I have a set of colors that I want to access easily and then cache.

This is the basically how I create my colors:

```
#define RGB(r, g, b) [self colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:1]

// [..]

+ (instancetype)pigletColor
{
    static UIColor *pigletColor = nil;
    if (!pigletColor) {
        pigletColor = RGB(237.0, 0.0, 130.0);
    }
    return pigletColor;
}
```

However, repeating the above ten times is not really neat and dry so I'm trying to create a macro allowing me to do this easily.

Ideally, I'd like to replace the above with `COLORGETTER(piglet, 234.0, 0.0, 130.0)`. I've had a go at it, but I can't get it to work. This is far as I got:

```
#define COLORGETTER(name, red, green, blue)\
+ (instancetype *)##name##Color\
{\
    static UIColor *##name##Color = nil;\
    if (!##name##Color) {\
        ##name##Color = RGB(red, green, blue);\
    }\
    return ##name##Color;\
}
```

However, the above doesn't work, as I can't figure out the `#`/`##` operators.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors:

- `(instancetype *)` should be `(instancetype)`. Similar to `id`, this is already a pointer.
- `##name##Color` should be `name##Color`. You want to concatenate the name and "Color"
  to a single token, but not the preceding token.

So this seems to work:

```
#define COLORGETTER(name, red, green, blue)\
    + (instancetype) name##Color\
    {\
        static UIColor * name##Color = nil;\
        if (!name##Color)\
        {\
            name##Color = RGB(red, green, blue);\
        }\
        return name##Color;\
    }
```

Comment: Nice one! My commit after this consisted of `37 additions and 223 deletions.`. Thanks! Had 24 color getters I could simplify. :)

Answer (score 3):

A few things

1. `instancetype` is already a pointer, don't use `instancetype *`.
2. You only need `##` *between* identifieres - `name ## Color`, not `## name ## Color`.
3. You should really use a `dispatch_once` block instead of the `if`.
4. Optional, but you don't really need the custom name for the locals. It's easier to just use one name.

```
#define COLORGETTER(name, red, green, blue)\
+ (UIColor *)name##Color\
{\
    static UIColor *color = nil;\
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;\
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{\
        color = RGB(red, green, blue);\
    });\
    return color;\    
}
```